# Function to return String, to input in JSON

Tags: python, json

My code currently is writing a file, using JSON objects.

Using os.walk, I am going through files and I like to have a function, which gives me their filetype. To save some time, I like to only use libmagic, if the file is not a JPG.

The Problem seems to be with the return. No matter what I input after that, it won't work.
Giving me different kinds of errors.

The function is:

```
def Typen():
    for files in filenames:
        if files.endswith(".jpg"):
            return str('jpg')
        else:
            magic.from_file(filepath, mime=True)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], because your question is very unclear. "it won't work" in particular is not a proper description. Also, extract and provide a [mcve] and revise whether this question is actually related to JSON or if the problem is independent thereof. That said, have you looked at the Python pathlib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)? Possibly much better than `os.walk`.

Comment: The problem is you *aren't* returning the return value of `magic.from_file`; you're *ignoring* it.

Comment: The other problem is that `Typen` will only return one value, because you return from inside the loop. You need to *accumulate* values in a list to return *after* the loop completes.